# Ansible integer comparison, doesn't recognize negative integers

Tags: ansible

Both of these equal false. I just need to determine if an integer is negative or positive.

```
- debug: 
    var: -1 < 0  # false

- debug: 
    var: 1 < 0  # false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` parameter of [`debug` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) takes a value of the **variable name** to debug.

You can't put arbitrary expressions there, it makes no sense <sup>*</sup>.

---

If you want to evaluate an expression, you need an `msg` parameter with a Jinja2 expression:

```
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ -1 < 0 }}"

- debug: 
    msg: "{{ 1 < 0 }}"
```

---

<sup>* unless you wanted to create the variable name dynamically, but it would require a more sophisticated expression.</sup>

Comment: I was just using debug as an example. This works too `when: "{{ count }} > 0"`

Comment: I have no clue what you wanted to say in your comment. You were using `debug` module in a wrong way.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out if I switched the negative number it works -

```
- debug: 
    var: -1 < 0   # false

- debug: 
    var: 1 < 0   # false

- debug: 
    var: 0 < -1   # false

- debug: 
    var: 0 < 1.   # true
```

Comment: `"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{0 < 1.}}"`